# Headset and speaker laptop suddenly not making a sound

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers

Maybe this thing causing the problem, so I changed my permission in registry editor (regedit) on HKEY_CLASS_ROOT and when I restart the laptop, suddenly my laptop not making a sound. I've tried all suggestions on the internet and on the support page Microsoft like:

- uninstall and install the driver also update the drive
- using SFC /scannow
- checking the setting sound, check the "allow the application to take exclusive control of this device" because the system sound on the volume mixer is missing when I'm using the speaker (not using a headset plugged) but if I'm using a headset the system sound shows, but still doesn't make a sound (the microphone headset is work by the way)
- restart my laptop after I changed something
- test the audio speaker playback (error showing failed to play test tone even I change the Hz )

The system sound not showing in the volume mixer:

[image: System sound not showing]

Also, my Realtek audio manager is missing. I don't know if the change that I tell at the first is causing this problem. The weird thing is, when I restart the laptop, my laptop password is required character input (not pin input as usual). I tell all the weird things that maybe cause this problem. Can you guys tell me what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Use System Restore to rollback Windows to its state before you updated sensitive entries in the registry. And don't do that again.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: I edit my question can u check again maybe there is something @harrymc

Comment: See [How to Do a System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html), and I do hope that you haven't disabled System Restore in Windows.

Comment: but that's really the problem? I mean because of i change permissions all of this happened? @harrymc

Comment: Most likely. So go back to a situation where everything works, and in the future avoid using such methods. Windows is fragile and can break easily.

Comment: I've changed my regedit before this one, but it doesn't cause this problem